# outputting a row of a vector

Tags: c++, loops, vector

I am learning c++ and I am currently at halt.

I am trying to write a function such that:

1. It takes in input a one dimensional vector and an integer which specifies a row.
2. The numbers on that row are put into an output vector for later use.

The only issue is that this online course states that I must use another function that I have made before that allows a 1d vector with one index be able to have two indexes.

it is:

```
int twod_to_oned(int row, int col, int rowlen){
return row*rowlen+col;
}
```

logically what I am trying to do:

1. I use this function to store the input vector into a temporary vector as a 2D matric with i as the x axis and y as the y axis.
2. from there I have a loop which reads out the numbers on the row needed and stores it in the output vector.

so far I have:

```
void get_row(int r, const std::vector<int>& in, std::vector<int>& out){

int rowlength = std::sqrt(in.size());
std::vector <int> temp;

for(int i = 0; i < rowlength; i++){           // i is vertical and j is horizontal
    for(int j = 0; j < rowlength; j++){
        temp[in[twod_to_oned(i,j,side)]];        // now stored as a 2D array(matrix?)
    }
}

for(int i=r; i=r; i++){
    for(int j=0; j< rowlength; j++){
        out[temp[i][j]];
    }

  }
```

I'm pretty sure there is something wrong in the first and last loop which turns into a 2D matric then stores the row.

I starred the parts that are incomplete due to my lack of knowledge.

How could I overcome this issue? I would appreciate any help, Many thanks.

Comment: In the comment below you stated that you want to: "*use a for loop aswell as the `twod_to_oned` function to make it into a temporary 2d array such that each element now has an i and j value assigned to it*" - what do you mean by that? What do you mean by "*temporary 2d array*"? And what do you mean by "*each element now has an `i` and `j` value assigned to it*"?

Comment: I think it's clear now. One more thing - what is `side`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> takes in input a one dimensional vector

but

```
int rowlength = std::sqrt(in.size());
```

The line of code appears to assume that the input is actually a square two dimensional matrix ( i.e. same number of rows and columns )  So which is it?  What if the number of elements in the in vector is not a perfect square?

This confusion about the input is likely to cuase your problem and should be sorted out before doing anything else.

Comment: How is that an answer, not a comment?

Comment: That's right. Such a type should be its own class with a vector, a width and a height (well, I suppose just one of the dimensions will suffice). Not just a vector, which does not provide sufficient information.

Comment: @Fureeish Because it is an explanation of the cause of the problem? Those do not go in the comments section. The comments section is for requesting clarification.

Comment: I would rather consider that a hint, if anything. The question states that the first loop should convert the input to 2D matrix (which itself is incorrect - it has undefined behaviour in form of accessing a `vector` out of bounds). Converting to 2D, at least for me, clearly states that the programmer is aware of the fact that the input was not originally a 2D array. It might be a flattened square matrix, which would make the quoted code absolutely correct

Comment: @James, so you would like to have the converted to 1D row, converted back to 2D? The goal seems a little unclear, since you appear to be trying to copy the flattened board to another 1D `std::vector`. Did you mean to have a *so called* 2D vector in form of `std::vector<std::vector<int>>`? That way you could access it by `[i][j]` syntax. Please clarify

Answer (score 0):

I think what you wanted to do is the following:

```
void get_row(int r, const std::vector<int>& in, std::vector<int>& out) {

    int rowlength = std::sqrt(in.size());
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> temp; // now a 2D vector (vector of vectors)

    for(int i = 0; i < rowlength; i++) {
        temp.emplace_back();    // for each row, we need to emplace it
        for(int j = 0; j < rowlength; j++) {
            // we need to copy every value to the i-th row
            temp[i].push_back(in[twod_to_oned(i, j, rowlength)]);
        }
    }

    for(int j = 0; j < rowlength; j++) {
        // we copy the r-th row to out
        out.push_back(temp[r][j]);
    }
}
```

Your solution used `std::vector<int>` instead of `std::vector<std::vector<int>>`. The former does not support accessing elements by `[][]` syntax.

You were also assigning to that vector out of its bounds. That lead to *undefined behaviour*. Always use `push_back` or `emplate_back` to add elements. Use `operator []` only to access the present data.

Lastly, the same holds true for inserting the row to `out` vector. Only you can know if the `out` vector holds enough elements. My solution assumes that `out` is empty, thus we need to `push_back` the entire row to it.

In addition: you might want to use `std::vector::insert` instead of manual `for()` loop. Consider replacing the third loop with:

```
out.insert(out.end(), temp[r].begin(), temp[r].end());
```

which may prove being more efficient and readable.  The inner `for()` look of the first loop could also be replaced in such a way (or even better - one could emplace the vector using iterators obtained from the `in` vector). I highly advise you to try to implement that.

Comment: Long story short: emplacement **creates** an element inside the container, while pushing / inserting results in (sometimes) creating a temporary and **copying** it to the container. One should always *consider* using emplacement over insertion, but it's not always the case that it's better. A fairly [good read](https://www.go4expert.com/articles/cpp-11-emplacement-vs-insertion-stl-t34582/). If you encounter the name "Scott Meyers" while maybe doing a little more research regarding this topic, you will likely find the best source